# Building API for model that has referenced attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mern

so my question is how can i display data of a model that has an attribute reference to another model? In this task i have Driver model that has attribute state which should reference another model called State that has a name attribute. I know hot to reference models in mongoose but i don't know how to build API for creating new Driver and displaying it.

Below is my Driver and State models

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Driver = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String
},
phone: {
    type: String
},
email: {
    type: String
},
deleted: {
    type: Boolean
},
state: { 
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    Ref: 'State'
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Driver', Driver);
```

This is model of State

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let State = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('State', State);
```

Currently my API are looking like this

```
driverRoutes.route('/').get(function(req, res){
    Driver.find(function(err, drivers){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error");
        } else {
            res.json(drivers);
        }
    });
});

driverRoutes.route('/:id').get(function(req, res){
    let id = req.params.id;
    Driver.findById(id, function(err, temp){
        res.json(temp);
    });
});

driverRoutes.route('/add').post(function(req, res){
    let temp = new Driver(req.body);
    temp.save()
        .then(temp =>{
            console.log(temp.state);
            res.status(200).json({'driver': 'driver added successfully'});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new driver failed');
        });
});
```

Route with / is to display all Drivers in table.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Driver model to look as below,

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    let Driver = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    phone: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    deleted: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    state: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, //this is the change made
        Ref: 'State'
    }
   });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Driver', Driver);
```

The second step is optional. That is, in your state model,

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let State = new Schema({
    _id:{
      type:Schema.Types.ObjectId //this is optional however
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('State', State);
```

That should help.

Comment: Sorry for late response :) i found solution in meantime, also i wanted to populate state of Driver model with State[name] which i didn't know how to do at that time. For anyone looking for something similar go to mongoose populate function documentation and your question will be answered :D

Comment: Great! Good luck with your project :)